# What, if any, is the point in demanding to copy-paste an entire Reddit page?

Tags: discussion

[Where to buy a judo uniform (judogi) in Tokyo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/85757/where-to-buy-a-judo-uniform-judogi-in-tokyo) this was word-by-word asked on Reddit, which I found and left a link to it. Then you idiots forced me to copy-paste a good 80% of it. What's the point? Reddit archives pages after six months, they do not change and the chances of Reddit disappearing off the Internet is incredibly small and the discussion in question was quite on point with perhaps one comment being irrelevant. I tried to make it shorter but there is some information lost unless I do copy the whole thing.

Comment: Steady on old mate, link only answers are shunned for whatever reason and it's just part of WHAT IS.  I upvoted your answer anyway also because WHAT IS. Take the good with the bad and crack on :)

Comment: StackExchange wants people to visit their site, not some other random page on the Internet.

Comment: @pnuts The question here was at first...erm...not so well asked. But if you don't mind, you can outline as own answer under what circumstances a link-only answer would be acceptable. Being in the Fortress of Commonality can be a bit boring, a voice of cool dissent could be refreshing.

Answer (score 13):

Keep cool.

The question itself was something I would have voted to close because it resembled too much a shopping question. But ok, let's let it be valid.

I can understand that you want to link to it because it is a completely
self-contained answer and reddit archives them. So copying an answer
from it seems to be a pointless exercise, accepted.

The problem is that the point of stackexchange is not linking to answers,
but *giving answers at once* so that the person asking the question
does not need to browse the web. And reddit can still be DDos'ed and
yes, it can vanish from the internet (Millenials, do you know what "Netscape" is ? No ?)

I also want to point out that stackexchange is voluntarily, nobody
**forces** you to copy-paste 80% of a question.

I would advise that you take some time and sleep over the business.
We could still talk over linked-only answers, but it seems currently
your blood is a little bit boiling.

Comment: I laughed out when I saw the mention of Netscape. Yes, I’m a millenial and I do, though ;)

Comment: @Jan how about Lynx?

Answer (score 6):

Quite simply: Stack Exchange’s model is questions and answers. Note that is says *answers* — not counterquestions, not links to answers, not ‘yes I need that, too’ comments, not saying thank you but *answers.*

There are a number of reasons why somebody might want an answer right below the question. Maybe their internet is tediously slow, incredibly expensive, or both. Maybe some sites are blocked but `*.stackexchange.com` isn’t on their machine. Maybe they trust voting here but not there.

Also note that nobody is forcing you to copy and paste. You can also quote and summarise. You can condense that page with information you get elsewhere. You can delete your post. (You can wait until it has an absolute value score of 3 to win a badge while doing so.)